# ¿Cómo hago que mis transiciones vuelvan a su lugar gradualmente cuando quito el :hover?

Tags: css, css3, css-transform, transition

Buenos días/tardes/noches gente de StackOverflow.
Estoy trabajando en un código de CSS e hice unas transiciones de tipo translate de forma que cuando les coloco el cursor (es decir, que se activa el :hover) se muevan hacia arriba tardando 0,75s en completarse la transición, pero cuando quito el cursor de encima vuelven de forma brusca a sus posiciones originales. ¿Cómo hago que también sea gradual la transición de vuelta?

Aquí el código en cuestión:

```
.product-img-1:hover, .product-img-2:hover, .product-img-3:hover, .product-img-4:hover, .product-img-5:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-3px);
       -moz-transform: translateY(-3px);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-3px);
         -o-transform: translateY(-3px);
            transform: translateY(-3px);
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.75s;
           -moz-transition-duration: 0.75s;
            -ms-transition-duration: 0.75s;
             -o-transition-duration: 0.75s;
                transition-duration: 0.75s;
}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar. Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
.product-img-1, .product-img-2, .product-img-3, .product-img-4, .product-img-5 {
           -webkit-transition-duration: 0.75s;
           -moz-transition-duration: 0.75s;
            -ms-transition-duration: 0.75s;
             -o-transition-duration: 0.75s;
                transition-duration: 0.75s;
}
```

que es darle la transition-duration al elemento directamente, no al pseudo elemento

Comment: Gracias amigo, me funcionó.